# Atom Processing having problems with folders with spaces

Tags: java, processing

I have recently starting using the Java based language Processing.
I started off with using the standard processing editor that has been installed on my Windows machine, but didn't quite take to it. It's not very customizable and lacks things like highlighting variable and function names throughout the code.

So I decided to use Atom instead, and so far it's been great. Although with one problem:
I can't build sketches that have spaces in their directories.
If I want to build a sketch that has the path...

C:\Users\Sulu\Documents\Processing\Test Sketches\Test\test.pde

I get the message:
DPI detection failed, fallback to 96 dpi
C:\Users\Sulu\Documents\Processing\Test does not exist.
[Finished in 1.008s]

I'm sure this is down to the fact that there is a space in the path.

My question is this. Is there anyway that I can get Atom, or maybe it is the 'processing-java.exe' I need to modify, to ignore space names in the path?
To automatically add doublequotes?

I'd be really grateful to any help with this as I have a lot of sketches that have spaces in their path names and renaming them all would be tedious.
Thanks.

Comment: This error doesn't make a ton of sense. The path should be fine. Does that path work if you open up `test.pde` in the Processing editor? If so, it's an issue with Atom, not Processing.

Answer (score 1):

It is a part of Processing language, it is a rule, just like syntax which you have to follow and can't be modified, at least as far as I know.

This is what the [official github wiki](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting) says -

> Names of sketches cannot start with a number, or have spaces inside. This is mostly because of a restriction on the naming of Java classes. I suppose if lots of people find this upsetting, we could add some extra code to unhinge the resulting class name from the sketch name, but it adds complexity, and complexity == bugs. :)

So, I am afraid there is no solution to your problem other than renaming your sketches, at least not *yet*!

**EDIT :**

Seems like I misinterpreted the question a little bit, I would suppose your sketch works with processing editor but not in external editors because they use cli to compile your project, and the instructions do contain the file path, which can not have spaces when present in bash, if they do, they need to be enclosed within quotes or spaces need to be "escaped" with `\`, which is again, controlled by processing and I don't think you can somehow modify "processing" to add quotes to paths during "building" or escape spaces `\` so the answer still remains the same.

Comment: Hey. Thanks very much for the answer. Good and bad news I guess.

Comment: But in OP's case, the name of the sketch is `test.pde`. It doesn't contain any spaces. It's just that the absolute path of the sketch contains spaces, which should be fine.